Short SK combinator expression with long reduction / Busy Beaver for SK combinators
Question (short and simple version):
Can anyone suggest a very short SK combinator expression with a ridiculously long, but still terminating, reduction path (ignoring loops)?
Question (longer version):
I note that my question above seems closely related to the study of Busy Beaver functions.  If we define BB_SK(n) to be the length of the longest terminating SK combinator reduction -- we might have to fix a reduction strategy, or declare that we ignore loops -- amongst all SK combinator terms of length at most n, then we can rephrase my question in more mathematical generality as asking: what if anything is known about BB_SK(n)?

The lambda term (λ 1 1) (λ 1 (1 (λ λ 1 2 (λ λ 2 (2 1))))) requires a number of reduction steps exceeding Graham's number [1], and translates to the following SK term:
S (S K K) (S K K) (S (S K K) (S (S K K) (K (S (K (S (K (S S (K (K (S (S (K S) K) (S K K)))))) (S (S K K)))) K))))
Generally, all the lower bounds on BBλ [2] translate to lower bounds on your BB_SK.
[1] https://github.com/tromp/AIT/blob/master/fast_growing_and_conjectures/melo.lam
[2] https://oeis.org/A333479
